# ZEND framework application.ini and bootstrapping

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping

I am confused about different ways to bootstrap ZF:
for example I can do this in application.ini:

```
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

and then I can do virtually the same? in bootstrap.php file:

```
protected function _initView(){
$view = new Zend_View();       
$view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
$viewRenderer =Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
$viewRenderer->setView($view);
return $view;
}
```

---

1) Are these methods virtually the same? or they work differently in the background?

---

2) Is there a reason to choose one over the other (I assume there's gotta be....)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application.ini uses the [Resource Plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) whereas the bootstrap class initializes plain objects. I see the advantage of resource loaders vs. an application/module specific bootstrap class in reusability.

If your bootstrap classes always look the same you might want to consider writing a resource loader that does it. It is also easier and more user friendly to configure (and you can mix both approaches, too).

Comment: Not to mention the built-in environment (dev / test / prod) switching and inheritance available in Zend_Config

Comment: but - I guess I don't understand how these settings are applied. What if I specify different settings in application.ini and bootstap file (like for example encodings above). Which one will be applied?

Comment: @Andre From memory, the Bootstrap `_init*` methods execute after the application resource plugins. Also, I think (this may or may not be correct) if your init method is named the same as a resource plugin (eg "view", "db", "layout", etc), it will execute instead of the plugin

Comment: Yes you are right, it will be executed after and overwrite the settings from the application.ini. I think redundant configuration like that should be avoided though.